# Problem with filling a Table in c# from a list

Tags: c#

I am working with `WindowsForm` and `C#` and I am filling out a `List<>` and everything is fine so far

In my `list<>` I have 103 records but when I pass to my `DataTable` no record appears only the headers, that is to say that when I receive my table everything shows in null

The truth is, I'm a little new to this and it's the first one that I'm working on.

```
List<MSProject.Task> tasks = new List<MSProject.Task>();
DataTable Tabla = new DataTable();
Tabla = ListToDataTable(tasks);
```

my code

```
public static DataTable ListToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        //special handling for value types and string
        if (typeof(T).IsValueType || typeof(T).Equals(typeof(string)))
        {

            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Value");
            table.Columns.Add(dc);
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
                dr[0] = item;
                table.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            {
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
            }
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        row[prop.Name] = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                }
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this always the case?  List of int/ list if string  / list of class?  which list are you trying to show?

Comment: Several strange things in there; why is it `static`? That `catch` looks pretty superstitious. [Use your debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) and tell us your findings.

Comment: really when I get to `retun table` I see that table and the records are null

Comment: Where are you showing this DataTable? please put the code of MSProject.Task class

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code and it's work, The problem I believe is that the MSProject.Task doesn't have any public properties and you are iterating only in properties. `PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));`

see the code below:

```
//with properties    
public class MSProject.Task 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string code {get; set;}
}

//no properties
public class MSProject.Task2 
{
    public string Name;
    public string code;
}


private void ShowRownsInGrid()
{
    //it works shows rows in DataGridView!
    List<MSProject.Task> tasks = new List<MSProject.Task>()
        {
            new MSProject.Task(){ Name = "Joao", code = "01215452124"},
            new MSProject.Task(){ Name = "Maria", code = "4564678"},

        };
        DataTable Tabla = new DataTable();
        Tabla = ListToDataTable(tasks);

        MessageBox.Show(Tabla.Rows.Count.ToString()); //Show '2'
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Tabla; //Show 2 rows
 }



private void DontShowRownsInGrid()
{
     //it doesn't work, no rows are displayed in the DataGridView!
     List<MSProject.Task2> tasks = new List<MSProject.Task2>()
        {
            new MSProject.Task2(){ Name = "Joao", code = "01215452124"},
            new MSProject.Task2(){ Name = "Maria", code = "4564678"},

        };
        DataTable Tabla = new DataTable();
        Tabla = ListToDataTable(tasks);

        MessageBox.Show(Tabla.Rows.Count.ToString()); //Show '2'
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Tabla; //does not show lines
 }
```